# How to access XBAP Application from Internet

Tags: wpf, firewall, xbap

I'm new to WPF Web Application.
I've created a test application and exported it to C:\Test Application with publish.htm file created.
I'm able to run the application on my PC but I'm unable to configure Windows Firewall so that application can be accessed from internet.
I've configured port forwarding on my broadband router to forward port 8080 to my laptop's port 80
I'm stucked here

Amit Saraf

Comment: Hi, what operating system are you using? Have you deployed your xbap to IIS? Have you used the publish command in vs directly, or are you using mage? Have you tried to just create some test index.html, and do you get through to it?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 Home Basic and IIS is not supported by it. I've used publish wizard to generate the files along with dependencies and also publish.htm is created by it

Comment: see answer below, it got a bit long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Acoording to **[this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731911.aspx)** on technet you may install iis on w7hbs.  I would advice you to do so, configure it and add a site for your xbap to publish, deploy it here. How to install IIS is described in the link. In w7 and windows server 2008+ IIS is "included" in features/roles. Remember to also configure your windows firewall! Try telneting your ip and port to see if you get through(also a feature btw!).

Another example is apache, but I've never used it to host xbap applications before. Maybe someone else has experience with that(linux-mono people :) )

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have done the same to install IIS and it says IIS is installed on my PC, but in Administrative Options IIS Manager is unavailable so how can i start it

Comment: @AmitSaraf I have never used anything other pro or ultimate before, and it's been awhile since I used w7 aswell for this. Don't have a w7 avaliable where I'm currently at, so I can't check for you. Maybe you should ask at technet? [Related Question](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770472(v=ws.10).aspx)